# Laravel 5.4 Zizaco/entrust - user soft delete

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, entrust

How can I prevent detaching of roles on user soft delete?
`$user->hasRole('subscriber')` => true
`$user->delete()`
`$user->hasRole('subscriber')` => false
`$user->restore()`
`$user->hasRole('subscriber')` => false

Answer (score 0):

Look at [EntrustUserTrait](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/src/Entrust/Traits/EntrustUserTrait.php) rows 69-80.

```
/**
 * Boot the user model
 * Attach event listener to remove the many-to-many records when trying to delete
 * Will NOT delete any records if the user model uses soft deletes.
 *
 * @return void|bool
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function($user) {
        if (!method_exists(Config::get('auth.model'), 'bootSoftDeletes')) {
            $user->roles()->sync([]);
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

I think you do not use Laravel's own SoftDeletes trait if you have not *bootSoftDeletes*.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use EntrustUserTrait;
    ...
```